# How to connect my Xamarin app with local mySQL server?

Tags: c#, mysql, xamarin.forms, server

I'm trying connect to mySQL server with code below: (just part of my whole code)

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
//...
public void ConnectToServer()
        {
            string ConnectionString = 
            "Server=DESKTOP-91JG566;Database=db_server;Uid=user;Pwd=123456A+;";
            MySqlConnection cConn = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            cConn.Open(); // this returns the exception
            serverStatus = cConn.Ping() ? serverStatus = "connected" : serverStatus = "disconnected";
        }
```

I'm using MySQL Workbench, there is my server with database https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxn84.jpg

The exception says: System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConfiguration' threw an exception.'

I have searched about it, and even though I enabled "SQL Server Debugging" in project properties, things are the same.
The problem might be caused because I have bad connection string, I am not sure.

My goal is to communicate with the server, query him, reveive orders etc...

Comment: direct access to a remote db server from a client is a terrible, horrible, really bad idea and you should not try it.  Please use a webservice layer

Comment: yeah, I am about to use rest api, but I thought this is needed for implementing the REST

Comment: no, the service talks to the db, the client talks to the service.  The client does not interact directly with the db

Comment: thank you, I see now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

As Jason already mentioned this is a horrible idea to do. Instead, I suggest you build some mini `REST API` or even use some of the `serverless` services out there.

When you have that REST API or Azure Function ready then you can communicate with them using your `C#` code, more precisely using `HttpClient` from the .NET.

Your mobile app will be the client which will "talk" to REST API, and REST API will proceed with your request and make the request to the DB, grab some data and return you JSON or XML which you can, later on, deserialize into C# objects and show to the user.

The most simple example is located on the `MS Docs` page [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/web-services/rest), so you can take a look.

Wishing you lots of luck with coding!